# Serial Port Port.Write() Command

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I'm curious as to why when I use the SerialPort.Write() command, the command I'm trying to send doesn't actually ever get sent. (Maybe it just sits in the buffer, or is just saved somewhere, I don't know). I have to use the SerialPort.BaseStream.BeginWrite() command to actually physically send that command. Why is that?

Thanks,

Carter

Answer (score 0):

The BeginWrite method on a stream calls the Write method synchronously, which means that Write method might block on some streams. To determine whether the current instance supports writing, use the CanWrite property.

[a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.write%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)!